# serialize images paths php and edit them - Laravel (php)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, serialization

i have a project table that have 3 images col each col can have multiple images i decide to upload the images then serialize the array of paths for each of them 
my problem is with the edit page who can i let the user delete some images and add new images and the store the end result in the database

i know that i can create pivot table and store the images there but i need a solution for this situation

i'm using laravel (php) and mysql

```
 $externalImages = $request->file('externalImages');
    $externalImagesPath=array();
    if(!empty($externalImages)){
        foreach ($externalImages as $key => $externalImage){
            if($externalImage->isValid()){
                $imageName = mt_rand(999,999999)."_".time()."_".$externalImage->getClientOriginalName();
                $externalImage->move(public_path('uploads/images/PropertyProject'),$imageName);
                $imagePath = "uploads/images/PropertyProject/".$imageName;
                array_push($externalImagesPath, $imagePath);
            }
        }    
    }
    $externalImagesPath = serialize($externalImagesPath);
```